# How do we use SqlDataReader obejct as an array?

Tags: asp.net

It might sound kiddish or silly but i wanna know that in codes like..

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
rdr.Read();
Response.Write(rdr[1]. ToString());
```

how do we use the `SqlDataReader` object as an array `(rdr[1])` without declaration?

What I want to know is, what is happening in the following line?

```
Response.Write(rdr[1].ToString());
```

Since rdr is an object, how art we able to use square brackets with that?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Indexers.

Please refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) link.

> Indexers are a syntactic convenience
>   that enable you to create a class,
>   struct, or interface that client
>   applications can access just as an
>   array

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.

```
 Object[] values = new Object[reader.FieldCount];
int fieldCount = reader.GetValues(values);

Console.WriteLine("reader.GetValues retrieved {0} columns.",
    fieldCount);
for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(values[i]);

Console.WriteLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, since SqlDataReader is a forward-only read-only stream of rows from a SQL Server database, the stream of rows will be looped through whether explicitly in your code or hidden in a framework implementation (such as DataTable's Load method). So you cannot directly convert it to array type. You need to convert it to list.

It sounds like using a generic list and then returning the list as an array would be a good option. For example,

List list = new List();

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
     list.Add(rdr.GetInt32(0));
}
```

return list.ToArray();